# Routing using iproute2 after NAT

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, iproute2

In a Linux system, which acts as a gateway on my lan, I tried to route traffic using iproute2.
Moreover, before routing it is necessary to perform the NAT, since
the linux machine is connected to a device which allow internet connection and it has 2 IP addresses `172.16.61.1` and `172.16.62.100`

I have 2 network cards with the following configuration :

```
DEVICE=eth3
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.150
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes  

DEVICE=eth4
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=172.16.61.2
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
GATEWAY=172.16.61.1
```

and I use the following instruction for ip translation via iptables

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.61.2
```

Using the aforementioned configuration, all computers belonging to the 192.168.1.0/24  network which have 192.168.1.150 as gateway are able to connect to the internet.

If I try to use iproute2 to configure the gateway, then I remove the default gateway from eth4 which assumes the following configuration :

```
DEVICE=eth4
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=172.16.61.2
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
```

AND I performed the following steps:

`1. In /etc/iproute2/rt_tables I have added the line` **1       route61**
`2. /sbin/ip route add 172.16.61.0/24 via 172.16.61.1 table route61 proto static`
`3. /sbin/ip route add default via  172.16.61.1 table route61 proto static`
`4. /sbin/ip rule add from 172.16.61.0/24 pref 15000 table route61`

The output of `/sbin/ip route show table route61` is

```
172.16.61.0/24 via 172.16.61.1 dev eth4  proto static  
default via 172.16.61.1 dev eth4  proto static
```

The output of `/sbin/ip rule show` is

```
0:      from all lookup local 
15000:  from 172.16.61.0/24 lookup route61 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

but in this case it doesn't work, what am I wrong?

I also tried to use `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-routes eth4`  with no success

What I need is to understand why I can't get "table based routing" to work as I will have to use it in a context with multiple gateways

**Update**

To try what is suggested by dirkt, I removed the default gateway

```
route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4
```

and I used:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 pref 15000 table route61
```

what happens is

1. the pc that uses 192.168.1.150 as GW, that is the pc object of this post, is able to connect to the internet
2. I can't connect to GW anymore unless I remove the instruction `ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 pref 15000 table route61`

With postrouting the packets coming from 192.168.1.0/24 shouldn't assume 172.16.61.2 as source address ?

If i use or remove default GW using `route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4` OR `route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4` and I do :

```
ip route get 216.58.205.78 from 192.168.1.5
```

I have `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`

if I use `ip route get 216.58.205.78 from 172.16.61.2` I have `216.58.205.78 from 172.16.61.2 via 172.16.61.1 dev eth4`

After `route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4` if I do :

```
nc -v 216.58.205.78 443
```

I have

```
Connection to 216.58.205.78 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

If I remove default GW `route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4` nc connects only if I specify source ip:

```
nc -v 216.58.205.78 443 -s 172.16.61.2
```

Comment: Is this about **routing**, or about **NAT**? You do not need to use NAT for routing. You only need it if this box is connected to something that needs a single IP address. If this is e.g. a home router, then you end up with double NAT. So please edit your question and add information about your **complete** network setup. And there are probably alternative network setups which may work better.

Comment: @dirkt I changed the introduction, I hope it is clearer now

Comment: Instead of `172.16.61.0/24 via 172.16.61.1 dev eth4  proto static`, you should have `172.16.61.1 dev eth4  proto static` or `172.16.61.0/24 dev eth4  proto static`. (Actually it could even be unnecessary.) Also you should have a single SNAT rule with NEITHER `-p tcp` NOR `-p udp`.

Comment: Besides, is there a proper reason for you to do policy routing? Seems unnecessary to me in your case.

Comment: @TomYan please see below

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have `192.168.1.0/24` on `eth3`, and you want to route and NAT that to something behind `eth4`, were it's unspecified what exactly is behind `eth4`, if it does DHCP, and if it needs static addresses or not.

(The usual case is that you have some kind of router behind `eth4`, which runs DHCP, and gives out addresses).

So first, the usual way to achieve that is to enable forwarding and do

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

where `$EXTIF` is your external interface (`eth4`). The `MASQUERADE` is `SNAT` with whatever address happens to be on `eth4`, so this is resilient against address reassignment. And if you don't mention protocols, just everything gets NAT'ed, which is usually what you want.

Second, there isn't any reason to do table based routing (unless there's additional details which you didn't explain). So forget about the tables, and if there's no DHCP behind `eth4` which would distribute the gateway information for the default route, just do

```
ip route default via 172.16.61.1
```

Assuming that `eth4` already got an address in `172.16.61.*/24`, this is enough (the `172.16.61.0/24` route gets set when you set the ip address).

But the best things is to just leave this to DHCP, if it's enabled on your router (I guess that would be `BOOTPROTO=dhcp`, if that is Red Hat).

---

If the problem is the policy routing: You want to route outgoing packets coming in from `192.168.1.0/24` via a default route in table `route61`, so you need to do

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 pref 15000 table route61
```

and not `from 172.16.61.0/24`.

That said, I am not actually sure how NAT interacts with policy routing. I'd **assume** the returning packets get deNATed first, and then the rules in the main table will route them correctly, but I've never tried that myself.

To debug, `ip route get X.X.X.X from Y.Y.Y.Y` may be helpful, as will `tcpdump` on both interfaces like you already did in the other question you mentioned.

It will also be easier to first try this without tables. Once that works, you know nothing else gets in the way, and you can try with tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you have identified what I proposed is part of a larger problem as you can see in 
https://superuser.com/questions/1664793/route-based-on-source-ip-address-via-2-gateways-on-same-nic 
Having not found a solution to the main problem, I am trying to face it by dividing it into sub-parts

Comment: Behind eth4 there is a vpn that allows me to access the internet

Comment: What I need is to understand why I can't get it to work
table based routing as I will have to use it in a context with multiple gateways

Comment: What I need is to understand why I can't get "table based routing" to work as I will have to use it in a context with multiple gateways

Comment: To try what you recommend
I removed the default gateway 
route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.61.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth4
and I used:
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 pref 15000 table route61

what happens is 
1) the pc that uses 192.168.1.150 as GW, that is the pc object of this post, is able to connect to the internet 
2) I can't connect to GW anymore unless I remove the instruction 
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 pref 15000 table route61


With postrouting the packets coming from 192.168.1.0/24 shouldn't assume 172.16.61.2 as address?

Answer (score 0):

Using a new routing table, you have to add even connected routes : `172.16.61.0/24 via 172.16.61.1 dev eth4  proto static` should be `proto scope link` instead with the source IP specified, and you miss the 192.168.1.0/24 route
Routing decision is performed before output / post routing nat so `ip rule add from` should use the original source IP.
[image]

```
# Configure tables
echo '2 table61' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
echo '3 table62' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 

# routing decision is performed before output / post routing nat
ip rule add from 192.168.1.5 lookup table62
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup table61

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.150 table table61
ip route add 172.16.61.0/24 dev eth4 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.61.2 table table61
ip route add default via 172.16.61.1 table table61

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.150 table table62
ip route add 172.16.62.0/24 dev eth4 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.62.100 table table62
ip route add default via 172.16.62.254 table table62
```

Also, I might have mixed your questions in my head, if it doesn't work immediately, could you please add the following to your question?

```
ip a
ip r show table table61
ip r show table table62
ip rule show
iptables -L -n -v
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```